# Pointing map to a new map inside a method looses effect after leaving method

Tags: go

This code, visible on the [Go PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/VeIRd60AThW):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyType map[int]int

func (x MyType) updateIt() {
    newItem := make(MyType)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        newItem[i] = i
    }
    x = newItem
    fmt.Println(x)
}

func main() {
    x := make(MyType)
    x.updateIt()
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Produces:

```
map[0:0 1:1 2:2]
map[]
```

While I expect:

```
map[0:0 1:1 2:2]
map[0:0 1:1 2:2]
```

**Why?**

My understanding is that: `x.updateIt()` takes `x` as an argument, then creates `newItem` and changes the pointer of `x` so that it points to `newItem`. So `x` points to the data of `newItem`. This seems to be indeed the case inside `updateIt`, as visible from the first print line. But when `x` is print after the method, the change is lost.

I'm new to Go and this is unexpected behaviour for me, could you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a pointer receiver:

```
func (x *MyType) updateIt() {
    newItem := make(MyType)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        newItem[i] = i
    }
    *x = newItem
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/K82TTjHdDgg

**Explanation**

Arguments "in front" of a function (so-called *receivers*) behave more or less like ordinary arguments.

Imagine a function like this:

```
func updateIt(x MyType) {
    newItem := make(MyType)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        newItem[i] = i
    }
    x = newItem
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Here, you pass x *by value*, not *by reference* (or as a pointer).

What happens is that x gets replaced inside the function, but keeps its original value outside of it. By passing a pointer you can replace the value to which x is pointing, thereby changing the value of x outside of the function.

See also "A Tour of Go, Pointers": https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Comment: Thanks, your code work. But I don't understand that explanation, because: maps are not supposed to be passed by value ever, are they? (they are pointers to a value by default as explained here: https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/30/if-a-map-isnt-a-reference-variable-what-is-it#:~:text=Maps,%20like%20channels,%20but%20unlike,a%20pointer%20to%20a%20runtime.&amp;text=Maps%20have%20the%20same%20pointer,value%20in%20a%20Go%20program. )

Comment: Indeed, it is possible to pass a mask and change it inside a function. But this is not what you were doing. You passed a map, but then created another one and assigned that new map to the local variable carrying the old map.

Comment: @NikolayShindarov In Go, all parameters are passed by value. Sometimes the value is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `main` function you create a new map and assign the pointer of that new map to `x`.

Then the value of that pointer is passed to the `updateIt` function.

Then inside `updateIt` you replace it with pointer to **another** map you create inside `updateIt`. Then it updates this new map instead of updating the original map created inside `main`

The most important thing to understand here is that your program creates two different maps.

So avoid creating two maps and update the same map passed to your `updateIt` function.

```
func (x MyType) updateIt() {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        x[i] = i
    }
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-MemfTv1uJV